# Spark Kafka Streaming - There a is a lot of delay in processing the batch

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am running spark streaming with kafka fro word count program, there is a lot of delay in batch creation and processing - around 2 mins for each batch.
How could i reduce this time ? Are there any properties to be configured this to be quickly as possible - like properties at spark streaming level or kafka level ?

Answer (score 0):

you should define the interval between each batch in your unstructured StreamingContext, exemple :

```
val ssc = StreamingContext(new SparkConf(), Minutes(1))
```

in strutured streaming you have a option: kafkaConsumer.pollTimeoutMs
with 512 ms as default value, more informations: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html

Another problem can come from the kafka lag. you application can take a long time to process a specific offset, maybe 2 minutes, so as soon as this offset is finish, he will poll others for processing. Try to look at the current offset of your consumer group and the last offset of your topic.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure this is spark streaming with kafka. The code snippet is not relevant. Point me to the specific property